# Bring down and delete bridge interface that's up

Tags: networking, bridge

How do I remove a bridge that has an IP address that was brought up manually and isn't in /etc/network/interfaces?

```
$ ifconfig br100                                                
    br100     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00                         
              inet addr:172.16.0.5  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Can't delete it:

```
# brctl delbr br100
bridge br100 is still up; can't delete it
```

Can't bring it down with ifdown:

```
# ifdown br100                                                  
ifdown: interface br100 not configured
```

Comment: Tried `ifconfig br100 down`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
# ip link set br100 down
# brctl delbr br100
```

Comment: To delete all bridge interfaces do `sudo ip link show | grep br- | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ' | while read b; do sudo ip link set "$b" down; sudo brctl delbr "$b"; done`

Comment: I stumbled upon an info that "brctl" is obsolete as of centos8 (and may be missing from the repos).  Use "ip" as in answer by robo

Comment: this might be useful, command to get the interface based on the ip `ifconfig | grep 172.16`

Answer (score 35):

```
$ sudo ip link delete br0 type bridge
```

that's all

Comment: That is if you are on a system with `iproute2` like e.g. GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: Is the "type bridge" really required here, seem it also works fine without this

Answer (score 16):

To clarify this for future.

`ifup` and `ifdown` are commands from some flavours of linux. And are used to control network settings set in `/etc/network/interfaces` for debian based systems and  `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg*` on Redhat based systems (I cannot comment on others).

Creating and removing interfaces manually is done by using `ifconfig` (or `ip` which is bit more tricky to use). Bridges can be controlled with `brctl`

So after removing all interfaces from a bridge with `brctl delif <bridg> <if>` 
it can be moved to "down state" with `ifconfig br100 down` (or `ip link set br100 down`) and can now be removed with `brctl delbr br100`

Please note that using `network-manager` to manage your networks might make your manually changed interfaces to reset.

Comment: There seems to be some division of labour between `brctl` and `ip/ifconfig` (as illustrated by the accepted answer above at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31765/262897) but also some overlap in functionality (as illustrated by e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324535/262897). So to say "Bridges can be controlled with `brctl`" seems to be only part of the story. Is there a simple way to summarize the relationship between the two/three?

Comment: `brctl` controls the bridge-device. E.g it binds the real network devices together to create a bridge-network device. The then created bridge-device is almost like any other network device and you control it with `ip/ifconfig` commands. To remove real-interfaces or the bridge, one has to first bring down the interface with `ip/ifconfig`.
In short, `brctl` controls bridge creation and interface bindings. `ip/ifconfig` control network interface (bridge device is also network interface) state and addresses.

Answer (score 14):

How about?

```
docker network prune
```

Comment: That won’t work if the bridge wasn’t configured by Docker, will it?

Comment: It probably won't but in my case solved the issue.

Comment: you solved my 3 days of desperation

Answer (score 10):

On macOS and possibly some BSD systems:

```
sudo ifconfig [bridge-name] down
sudo ifconfig [bridge-name] destroy
```

Comment: Worked for me on FreeBSD!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to delete all the interfaces linked to your bridge using this command

```
ovs-vsctl del-port br-ex INTERFACE_NAME
```

Then you can delete the bridge

```
ovs-vsctl del-br br-ex
```

Answer (score 1):

Also run:

```
virsh net-list --all  
sudo virsh net-list --all   
sudo virsh net-destroy default  
sudo virsh net-undefine default  
[...]  
sudo nmcli connection show
sudo nmcli connection delete br0
[...]
```

before using the command in robo's answer if you're using GNU/Linux.