# Cannot delete bridge - "bridge br0 is still up; can't delete it"

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, bridge

I have the same problem as this guy : [Bring down and delete bridge interface that's up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/bring-down-and-delete-bridge-interface-thats-up)

But that solution does not work for me.

I remove all interfaces from the bridge using brctl delif .
I then set the link to down using either ifconfig or ip.
I then try to remove the bridge using brctl br0 "bridge br0 is still up; can't delete it".

The platform is Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi.

Any ideas?

Identical output from ifconfig and ifconfig -a :

```
br0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:e6:fc:89:be:4b
      inet6 addr: fe80::56e6:fcff:fe89:be4b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:6569 (6.4 KiB)

eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:47:0d:a5
      inet addr:192.168.2.29  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe47:da5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:25109 (24.5 KiB)  TX bytes:64247 (62.7 KiB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

mon.wlan1 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 54-E6-FC-89-BE-4B-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:62535 (61.0 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:84:f8:3f
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:17 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:3828 (3.7 KiB)  TX bytes:1294 (1.2 KiB)

wlan1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:e6:fc:89:be:4b
      inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::56e6:fcff:fe89:be4b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:21016 (20.5 KiB)
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `ifconfig` and `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: Then `br0` is still up. So it's not surprising that you get the error you get. Maybe try `ifconfig br0 down`?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I already tried that.  Both using ifconfig and ip link.

Comment: Maybe you have some kind of daemon running and automagically starting available network devices? Whatever is happenning, you need it to stop being UP before destroying the bridge.

Comment: Removing all Jails and plugins resolved this for me.

Comment: This is a double of [bring down and delete bridge interface thats up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31763/bring-down-and-delete-bridge-interface-thats-up). There is a working answer.

Answer (score 42):

According to the other post you've already linked, this shuld help

```
ifconfig br0 down
brctl delbr br0
```

Comment: I already tried that. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question.

Answer (score 11):

```
ifconfig br100 down
```

or

```
ip link set dev br100 down
```

Comment: 2nd option worked for me and first one not.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the package bridge-utils and br0 seemed to disappear. This solution is of course only acceptable if you don't need any other bridges, which I don't.

Comment: that's called the sledgehammer approach =)

Answer (score 2):

Remove all network interfaces from the bridge:

```
brctl delif brX ethX
```

Bring the bridge down:

```
ifconfig brX down
```

Remove the bridge:

```
brctl delbr brX
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem on raspberry pi. When I tried to remove a bridge, E.g `brctl delbr br0` I got

```
bridge br0 is still up; can't delete it
```

I tried what [Bonsi Scott](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62776/82986) suggested, but I had no success.

So I did a `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bridge                 90721  0
```

and saw that the bridge module is not in use.

I don't understand why I can't remove the bridge if the module is not in use.

As a workaround I unloaded the kernel module.

```
modprobe -r bridge
```

and loaded the module again

```
modprobe bridge
```

Both (unload and load) worked and the bridge interface was gone. I verified this with `ifconfig`.

Hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In worst case, You would need to turn off all network services and then from console try deleting it. It should work.